# Building a stacking layout with CSS Flexbox

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, styles

I've got a technical test for a job interview, and I'm struggling with what should be a simple layout!

I need a two column design where by divs are stacked above each other as per:

[image: desired Layout]

which will then change for smaller screens to:

[image]

I thought I knew flexbox quite well, but it turns out I obviously don't, the closest I can get (which is no where near...) is

[image]

using

```
 <head>
  <style>
  .container{
    width:600px;
    min-height:300px;
    background-color: blue;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .small{
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    margin:20px;
  }
  .big{
    width: 250px;
    height:250px;
    background-color: green;
    margin:20px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="big">Widget 1</div>
    <div class="small">Widget 2</div>
    <div class="small">Widget 3</div>
    <div class="big">Widget 4</div>
    <div class="small">Widget 5</div>
    <div class="small">Widget </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I've searched for hours, and I can't get anything close! Can anyone point me in the  right direction?

Comment: The example graphics look like they're using float rather than flexboxes, tbh. Anyway, will a media query be considered cheating?

Comment: Is using flexbox mandatory? Or would grid be allowed also?

Comment: The multiple layouts is not possible in flexbox without additional wrappers & `display:contents`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use floats, floating the larger `.widget` elements to the left and the smaller `.widgets` elements to the right of the `.container` element on larger screens:

```css
/*IGNORE STYLE RULES BETWEEN HERE...*/

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  counter-reset: widget;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.widget::after {
  color: white;
  content: "widget-" counter(widget);
  counter-increment: widget;
  font-family: monospace;
}


/*...AND HERE*/

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  /*Stops container height from collapsing*/
}

.widget {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.widget--small {
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 390px) {
  .widget--small {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 100px;
  }
  .widget--small:nth-child(5) {
    margin-top: -30px;
    /*offsets the extra spacing between elements*/
  }
}

.widget--big {
  background: green;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 390px) {
  .widget--big {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="widget widget--big"></div>
  <div class="widget widget--small"></div>
  <div class="widget widget--small "></div>
  <div class="widget widget--big"></div>
  <div class="widget widget--small"></div>
  <div class="widget widget--small"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [flexbox order property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), to re-order the items on the mobile view. For the desktop view, take a look at [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp), to have different styles for different viewports.

```css
.grid-container {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}

.widget {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.item1 {
  order: 1;
}

.item2 {
  order: 2;
}

.item3 {
  order: 4;
}

.item4 {
  order: 3;
}

.item5 {
  order: 5;
}

.item6 {
  order: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="widget item1 green">1</div>
  <div class="widget item2">2</div>
  <div class="widget item3">3</div>
  <div class="widget item4 green">4</div>
  <div class="widget item5">5</div>
  <div class="widget item6">6</div>
</div>
```